# Prove that in every non bipartite graph there are two adjacent vertices both of even or odd degree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a non-bipartite graph with more than 3 vertices.
Prove that it contains adjacent vertices $v,u$ such that $d(v)+d(u)$ is even.

edit:
I have proven that if there aren't any such vertices then G must be bipartite:
we can simply partition G in X and Y where X contains vertices of odd degree and Y contains vertices of even degree.
This however doesn't prove the existence of such v,u in a non-bipartite graph.

Comment: The question title and body don't seem to match. The title has the constraint of same degree, but the body only requires the sum-degree to be even. What is to be proved? And what have you tried?

Comment: sorry, i already edited the title to match the question, the sum-degree has to be even. i'm not sure which property of non-bipartiteness i must use for the proof, i was trying "contains odd cycle", but it got me nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $d(v)+d(u)$ is always odd for any adjacent vertices $v$, $u$ then the graph is bipartite: take the set of vertices $v$ such that $d(v)$ is even and the set of vertices $u$ such that $d(u)$ is odd.

Comment: I have already proven this, was just editing the original answer, i just thought this doesn't help with showing that these vertices exist for all non-bipartite graphs.

Comment: @Mano Plizzi My proof is by contradiction. If there are no adjacent vertices such that $d(u)+d(v)$ is even then $d(u)+d(v)$ is always odd which implies that $G$ is bipartite.

Comment: Yes, the question was, if you are given a non bipartite graph, show that these two vertices exist, what you (and I) have shown is that there is no bipartite graph that contains those vertices.

Comment: @Mano Plizzi The linear graph $1-2-3-4$ is bipartite and $d(2)+d(3)=4$ is even.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you have shown that if there are no such vertices v,u then the graph must be bipartite. This, i believe, still doesn't prove that *all* non-bipartite graphs contain such vertices.

Comment: @Mano Plizzi They are equivalent statements: $P\Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, got it now, thank you for bearing with me

Comment: @Mano Plizzi You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is non-bipartite, then it contains an odd cycle, forcing two adjacent vertices on that cycle to share the same degree and thus proving the existence of two vertices whose degree-sum is even.